# Always allow session cookies setting in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

Always allow session cookies setting using c#.

How to change **always allow session cookies** in internet explorer using coding, means by changing registry setting.

Please specify registry location and value need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**How to enable session cookies in your browser:**

**Netscape Navigator 4.x (Windows and Mac):**

1. Click the Edit menu and select Preferences.
2. Click on Advanced in the list of topics on the left side of the window. The right side of the window should now display a series of checkboxes.
3. Find the box labeled Accept all cookies and make sure it is checked.
4. Click OK.

**Microsoft Internet Explorer For Windows - Version 5.xx**

1. Click the Tools menu and select Internet Options.
2. Click the Security tab at the top of the window.
3. The box at the top of the window should read Internet Zone.
4. The bottom section of the Security window contains several buttons. Click the one marked Custom.
5. Scroll down the list of options until you see the Cookies heading.
6. In the Allow per-session cookies (not stored),click on the Enabled button.
7. In "Allow cookies that are stored on your computer," click on the Enabled button.
8. Click on OK.

**Microsoft Internet Explorer For Windows - Version 6.xx**

1. Click on the Tools menu and select Internet Options.
2. Click the Privacy tab at the top of the window.
3. Make sure that the slider is set at a level not higher than Medium.
4. The bottom of the slider section of the Security window contains several buttons. Click on the one marked Advanced.
5. In the new window under the Cookies section, check the box labeled "Override automatic cookie handling".
6. Now you will see the other settings that are enabled and can be configured.
7. Under the First-party Cookies section, click the Accept button.
8. Under the Third-party Cookies section, click on the Block button.
9. Check the box labeled "Always allow session cookies."

   1. Click on OK.
   2. Click on OK.

**Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.x (Mac)**

1. Click on the Edit menu and select Preferences.
2. In the left pane, under the heading "Receiving Files," click on Cookies.
3. In the right pane, find the pull-down menu next to "When receiving cookies" and select Never ask.
4. Click on OK.

Comment: Manish, that is not which I want. I want to change this setting by using some code in c#. Not by opening internet explorer and checking that check for always allow session cookies. so We need to know the registry location where this setting is saved by internet explorer.